# Specifications for a flyback transformer

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, flyback

I'm building an SMPS that takes in 110/220V AC and outputs +/- 3.3V DC. The chosen topology is flyback and as is the case of flyback transformers, I need to get one custom made. I have the Np:Ns and Naux:Ns turns ratios and I was hoping anyone here would help me know and state what other attributes I need to specify to the manufacturer.

Comment: Flyback for step down???? Flyback convertors are especially good at stepping voltages up.

Comment: Or for isolation. Or for AC/DC convertion (with rectifier of course)

Comment: @Gregory Yep this is an isolated AC to DC converter using TI's UCC28722.

Comment: What is used on evaluation board? Take something similar.

Comment: The evaluation board has an output of 5V at 1A and the xformer they've used is not available in my part of the world.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you designed transformer as per spec. You need to specify the Following things to the transformer manufacturer.
      1. Bobbin and core
      2. Wire gauge details for correspond winding.
      3. Turns Ratio. 
      4. Primary inductance and Leakage inductance of the Transformer.

Comment: Thanks. How do I decide the bobbin, core and wire gauge? I did not have to take into account these and their attributes when I was running through the chip's design walkthrough.

Comment: Check out below link https://www.fairchildsemi.com/application-notes/AN/AN-4137.pdf